# Does Response.Redirect work in Application_AcquireRequestState?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I am checking for a header value and compare it to a session variable:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if header does not match session, redirect to login page.
    Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
}
```

If they don't match, I want to redirect to login page. It seems as if the Redirect is not fired. When debugging, it will hit that line of code and it seems as if all processing is stopped but no redirection.

Should I try a different event handler? My problem is I need to be able to access the Response.Headers and Session state to check. And in the AcquireRequestState I can access all the data I need but can't get the redirect to work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather try `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath`. `Response.Redirect` sends redirect headers to the client, which in turn calls the new URL. My guess is you want it all to happen server-side, which is what `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` or `Server.Transfer` would do.